# Как повторять аудио-воспроизведение?

Tags: javascript

Есть игра на Canvas HTML5 и нужно после прерывания воспроизведения повторять данное аудио постоянно. Пробовал с помощью location.reload(); ,но чуть с ума не сошел)))

Какие есть у вас идеи?

```
var game = document.getElementById('game');
var ctx = game.getContext('2d');
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
ctx.shadowColor = "white";
ctx.shadowBlur = 200;
var supercell_loading = new Image();

var bg = new Image();
var supercell_loading_audio = new Audio();
var supercell_menu_audio = new Audio();

bg.src = 'style/brawl-stars-big-logo.jpg';
supercell_loading.src = 'style/LOGO_LOADING.PNG';
supercell_loading_audio.src = 'style/s.mp3';
supercell_menu_audio.src = 'style/meenu.mp3';

function supercell_loading_function() {
    supercell_loading_audio.play();
    ctx.drawImage(supercell_loading, 532, 238, 160, 130);  
}

function draw_menu() {
    supercell_menu_audio.play();
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 1292, 633);
    // 450 550 420 30

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(450, 550, 420, 30);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}
setTimeout(supercell_loading_function, 2000); //2000
setTimeout(draw_menu, 4000); //4000
```

Answer (score 0):

Несложно заметить, что Canvas к вопросу никак не относится, всё дело в работе с `Audio`.

Попробуйте

```
myAudio = new Audio('someSound.ogg');
myAudio.loop = true;
myAudio.play();
```

В старых браузерах [может потребоваться](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3273552/3995261) обходной вариант:

```
myAudio = new Audio('someSound.ogg'); 
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
myAudio.play();
```

Comment: Да, извините, не заметил, а про loop совсем забыл, ведь он даже в HTML есть, хотя вроде в HTML5 не работает, а вам спасибо большое, все работает :)

Comment: @user370535 если работает, примите ответ (нажмите на галку слева)